# Как из данных вычленить некие группы данных по условию

Tags: r

Есть dataframe с данными

```
dat
  cluster1 cluster2 cluster3 cluster4 cluster5 target.label
1        24        5       18       21       16            1
2         2       15       12        7       22            1
3        13       13       16       29       24            0
4        23       28       22       10        4            1
5         6       12       20       25       11            0
6        25       17       14       24       25            1
7        30       27        2        4       14            0
8        11        2       21        6        9            0
9        20       20       29       17       10            1
10        7       30       25       11       15            0
11       19        8       15        8       18            0
12        3       18        1       16       26            0
13       17        9       23       14        8            0
14        5        6        5       22       19            0
15        9       19        9       12       20            1
16       21        3        3       13       23            1
17       10       16        4       26        2            1
18       18        4       28        3        6            0
19       28       24        7       20       12            0
20        8       11       11       23        7            1
21       15       14        6       27       27            0
22       26       29       26       28       29            1
23       16        1       10        2       17            0
24        1        7       17       15       21            0
25       27       23       30        5       13            1
26       12       22       19        9       30            1
```

В данных у нас колонки с кластерами с диапазоном от 1 до 30 каждый и последняя колонка с целевой которая может иметь значения 0 или 1

нужно найти такие строчки которые повторяются не менее 10 раз в всей выборке и в каждой из найденных одинаковых групок которые повторялись, количество "1" в target.label должно превышать 70% по отношению к "0"

типа так

```
cluster1 cluster2 cluster3 cluster4 cluster5  target.label
1        24        5       18       21       16            1
2        24        5       18       21       16            1
3        24        5       18       21       16            0
4        24        5       18       21       16            1
5        24        5       18       21       16            1
6        24        5       18       21       16            1
7        24        5       18       21       16            1
8        24        5       18       21       16            0
9        24        5       18       21       16            1
10       24        5       18       21       16            1
.....
.....
......
```

вот найденные одинаковые строчки
единичек больше чем нулей...

как такое можно реализовать, и важно чтобы максимально быстро так как вычислений таких будет очень много

Comment: Посмотри пакет `partykit`.

Comment: Можете показать кодом? а то я посмотреть посмотрел, но мало чего понял

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот более элегантное решение. И главное - спользуются только пакеты `dplyr` и `tidyr`, что обеспечивает, вероятно, максимальную скорость исполнения. Все дальнейшие комментарии в коде.

```
library(tidyverse) # это удобный способ подгрузить сразу весь мир пакетов Hadley 

# создаем данные, подходящие по описанию - миллион наблюдений
df_raw <- data_frame(cluster1 = sample(0:9,1e6,replace = T),
                     cluster2 = sample(0:9,1e6,replace = T),
                     cluster3 = sample(0:9,1e6,replace = T),
                     cluster4 = sample(0:9,1e6,replace = T),
                     cluster5 = sample(0:9,1e6,replace = T),
                     target.label = sample(0:1,1e6,replace = T))

# создаем переменную со всей последовательностью
df <- df_raw %>% unite(seq, cluster1:cluster5, sep = '-', remove = F) 


df_count <- df %>% select(seq,target.label) %>%
        group_by(seq) %>% # группируем по последовательностям
        summarise(size = n(), # размер группы (сколько раз встречается последовательность)
                  target = sum(target.label), # просто суммируем 
                  share = target/size) %>% # считаем долю единиц
        ungroup()

# отбираем последовательности, которые удовлетворяют заданному условию
df_cond <- df_count %>% filter(size >= 10, share >=.7)

# если надо, можно слить результат с исходной таблицей, чтобы знать, какие конкретно
# наблюдения удовлетворяют условию
df_back <- left_join(df, df_cond %>% transmute(seq, cond = 'yes'), by = 'seq') %>%
         replace_na(replace = list(cond = 'no')) # (UPD) заменить пустые значения на 'no'
```

Comment: спасибо вам, добрые люди:) все получилось

Answer (score 3):

Ниже приведен фрагмент кода, решающий задачу. Проверен.

```
# основная идея на основании заданного дата фрэйма создать новый в котором посчитано
# для уникального сочетания строк по полям cluster1, cluster2, ... 
# количество с 0-ми, 1-ми и общее количество строк
# исключаем строки не удовлетворяющие требуемым условиям и в дальнейшем новый дата фрэйм
# используем как эталон для выборки из заданного дата фрэйма
library(dplyr)
# файл с данными 
data.file <- "/home/UserName/Документы/questions_586979/dtfrm.csv"
Mx.Sz <- 2     #10 - переменная для граничного условия "нужно найти такие строчки которые повторяются не менее 10 раз в всей выборке"
# для прогона тестового примера определяем 2
Mx.Prcnt <- 60     # переменная для граничного условия "в каждой из найденных одинаковых групок которые повторялись, количество "1" 
# в target.label должно превышать 70% по отношению к "0"
# для прогона тестового примера определяем 60%
# открываем файл с данными
df <- read.csv2(data.file)
# создаем два дополнительных столбца, по количеству возможныйх значений в target.label
# trgt.lbl.0 и заполняем 1 если значение target.label = 0
# trgt.lbl.1 и заполняем 1 если значение target.label = 1
df.tmp1 <- mutate(df, cluster1, cluster2, cluster3, cluster4, cluster5, 
                  trgt.lbl.0 = ifelse(target.label == 0, 1, 0), 
                  trgt.lbl.1 = ifelse(target.label == 1, 1, 0))
# производим группировку по полям cluster1, cluster2,... 
df.tmp2 <- group_by(df.tmp1, cluster1, cluster2, cluster3, cluster4, 
                            cluster5)
# суммируем по столбцам trgt.lbl.0, trgt.lbl.1 для определения количества 0 и 1 в строке 
# далее используем для определения % соотношения количества строк с 1 к общему количеству строк
# для уникального сочетания cluster1, cluster2 ...
# определяем количество строк с уникальным сочетанием значений по полям cluster1, cluster2 ...
# далее количество строк используем для исключения строк не удовлетворяющий условию Mx.Sz
df.tmp3 <- summarise(df.tmp2, sm.0 = sum(trgt.lbl.0), 
                              sm.1 = sum(trgt.lbl.1), 
                              all.rc = n())
# создаем поле sm.1.prcnt - значение которого показывает количество % строк с 1-ми к общему количеству
# для уникального сочетания cluster1, cluster2 ...
df.tmp4 <- mutate(df.tmp3, sm.1.prcnt = sm.1*100/all.rc)
# исключаем строки не удовлетворяющих нашим граничным условиям
# по общему количеству строк и процентному соотношению строк с 1-ми
# в результате получили дата фрэйм содержащий необходимые нам строки
df.tmp5 <- filter(df.tmp4, all.rc >= Mx.Sz & sm.1.prcnt >= Mx.Prcnt)

# в цикле на основании строк, удовлетворяющих требованиям, выбираем строки из исходного дата фрэйма 
# с последующей записью в файл
for (i in 1:nrow(df.tmp5)) {
  # результирующий дата фрэйм
  df.tmp6 <- filter(df, as.integer(cluster1) == as.integer(df.tmp5[i, 1]) &
                        as.integer(cluster2) == as.integer(df.tmp5[i, 2]) &
                        as.integer(cluster3) == as.integer(df.tmp5[i, 3]) &
                        as.integer(cluster4) == as.integer(df.tmp5[i, 4]) &
                        as.integer(cluster5) == as.integer(df.tmp5[i, 5]))
  # имя результирующего дата фрэйма
  nm.rslt <- paste0("nm.rslt.",i, ".csv")
  # записываем результат
  write.csv(df.tmp6, file = nm.rslt, row.names=FALSE)
}
```